# How to get the latest objects from NSFetchedResultsController with a limit?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Maybe the title of question is not apriopriate, but here is what I need to achieve with my `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
private func setupOnceFetchedResultsController() {

    if fetchedResultsController == nil {
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()
        let fetchReguest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WLComment")
        let createdAtDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)

        fetchReguest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "item.identifier = %d", item.identifier)
        fetchReguest.sortDescriptors = [createdAtDescriptor]
        fetchReguest.fetchLimit = 10

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchReguest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Suppose I have about **100** comments. The oldest on the top, and the latest on the bottom. There is no problem when I need to display all of them, but here I need only **10** of them. The above `NSFetchedResultsController` will display the first 10 of 100 messages, but I need to display the latest 10.

**Is there a way to let it know what I need?**

Comment: What about changing "ascending" to false ?

Comment: it is ok then, but it will be displayed in the table from the latest on top to the oldest on the bottom, so reversed, and not what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are going to use the data later on, you can choose from at least two options:

- revert the sort descriptor, will return the end of the sorted list with reverted order;
- get the number of items first and set the appropriate `fetchOffset`, will return the required number of items, ordered as needed.

Comment: Reverted order is not what I expect. How to get the number of items first?

Comment: Fetch it from Core Data

Comment: I believe you'll need to use a separate fetch request to do that, there might be an SQL query that would do it all in one go, if the data set is large enough and performance is critical I suggest you research it further.

Comment: but, this is why I use `NSFetchedResultsController` to not to fetch anything from core data manually.